# Codename One: Command button on top-bar and bottom-bar

Tags: codenameone

I have problem with Command with Codename One.

I want to make a UI like this: Command "Cancel" at top-left, Command "Account", "Images" at bottom bar

[image]

To do that, I added 4 command like this:

[image]

I added "empty" Command 217 to top-right, and next: Cancel, Account, Images (2 commands used icons)

It showed well on iPhone Simulator. But on Android simulator, it showed:

[image]

The "empty" command is showed, it made user confuse

But if I don't add "empty" command, the UI on iPhone will:

[image]

It doesn't like my design.

Everybody, can you help me any idea.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SideMenuBar](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/on-the-side-up-on-top) or the new [Toolbar API](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/cats-in-toolbars) which will be a part of the new update this week.

Comment: Thanks, but my client required that UI. Do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: Its unclear what you mean by "that" UI? Do you have a screenshot of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/35dcfc9827c382f96d04ae6e583e7311, this is screenshot that I need to do, the "cancel" button maybe put at left or right of top bar. Thanks.

Comment: Just add the cancel command as a command, what's the problem?
You can just add the other commands as buttons to a container at the bottom portion of the screen (e.g. south with border layout).

Comment: Oh, yeah. So I will custom themes for these button, maybe make background image for these buttons, right ? Thank for your help!